# Flask web app not working on heroku but works normally on localhost

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have a problem on my **Python Flask Web App**.

My code **works normally without any error on localhost**. 
But after I have **deployed it on Heroku with the same code and files**, it gave me **error 500** when I perform a search on the web app.

I already tried to put **global** in front of the variables, but it still fails. I didn't know the proper way to do so.

https://unifit-web-app.herokuapp.com/

On localhost:
[image: localhost]

On heroku app:
[image: heroku]

**Logs** in heroku app:

```
[2019-06-28 08:09:43,471] ERROR in app: Exception on /result [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/app/unifit.py", line 16, in result
results = extract(query)
File "/app/unifit.py", line 86, in extract
lazada = data['itemListElement']
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
10.13.226.47 - - [28/Jun/2019:08:09:43 +0000] "POST /result HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "https://unifit-web-app.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
```

This is the **full code** of my web app excluding the template files, unifit.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from functools import wraps
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

app = Flask(__name__)

# Results
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    query = request.form['keyword']
    results = extract(query)
    return jsonify(results)

class Products(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, price=None, image=None, url=None, origin=None):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.image = image
        self.url = url
        self.origin = origin

# Extract
@app.route('/extract', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def extract(keyword):
    global link
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = {}
        x['items'] = []

        # Shopee Starts Here
        l1 = []

        url = "https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/"

        querystring = {"by":"relevancy","keyword":keyword,"limit":"20","locations":"-1","match_id":"174","newest":"0","order":"desc","page_type":"search","rating_filter":"4"}


        payload = ""
        headers = {
        'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
        'accept': "*/*",
        'x-api-source': "pc",
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        'if-none-match-': "55b03-e2b4b3f247507f7c1a18fda4a09f1340",
        'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
        'connection': "keep-alive",
        'host': "shopee.com.my"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        results = json_data["items"]

        for item in results:
            name = item["name"]
            price = float(item["price"])/100000
            imagex = item["image"]
            image = "https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/" + imagex
            shopid = item["shopid"]
            itemid = item["itemid"]
            url = "https://shopee.com.my/"+name+"-i."+str(shopid)+"."+str(itemid)
            origin = "Shopee"

            l1.append(Products(name, float(price), image, url, origin))

        # Shopee Ends Here

        # Lazada Starts Here
        l2 = []

        page_link = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q='+keyword+'&sort=priceasc'
        page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
        page_content = soup(page_response.text, "html.parser")

        json_tags = page_content.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})
        for jtag in json_tags:
            json_text = jtag.get_text()
            data = json.loads(json_text)

        lazada = data['itemListElement']

        for item in lazada:
            name = item["name"]
            image = item["image"]
            price = item["offers"]["price"]
            url = item["url"]
            origin = "Lazada"

            l2.append(Products(name, float(price), image, url, origin))

        # Lazada Stops Here

        # Lelong Starts Here
        l3 = []

        url = "https://www.lelong.com.my/catalog/all/list?TheKeyword="+keyword+"&CategoryID=51"

        payload = ""
        headers = {
            'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
            'accept': "*/*",
            'x-api-source': "pc",
            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
            'if-none-match-': "55b03-e2b4b3f247507f7c1a18fda4a0f91340",
            'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
            'connection': "keep-alive",
            }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        #print(response.text)
        page_content = soup(response.text, "html.parser")

        json_tags = page_content.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})
        for jtag in json_tags:
            json_text = jtag.get_text()
            json_dict = json.loads(json_text)

        lelong = json_dict['itemListElement']

        for item in lelong:
            name = item["name"]
            image = item["image"]
            price = item["offers"]["price"].replace(',', '')
            url = item["url"]
            origin = "Lelong"

            l3.append(Products(name, float(price), image, url, origin))

        # Lelong Stops Here

        # Combine result
        mergelist = l1+l2+l3
        import operator
        mergelist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('price'))

        # Tukar dari list ke json
        for elem in mergelist:
            x['items'].append({  
                'name': elem.name,
                'price': float(elem.price),
                'image': elem.image,
                'url': elem.url,
                'origin': elem.origin
            })

        #print(json.dumps(x, indent=2))
        mergelist = json.dumps(x, indent=2)

    return mergelist

# Main
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')

# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I already tried to put global in front of the variables"—please don't do this unless you have a specific reason to. This shouldn't be a blind point-and-shoot troubleshooting technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating data list/dictionary within `for jtag in json_tags` loop and you're trying to access data[ ] outside it! Not sure if you declared global data[ ], cause I don't see that in your posted code.

EDIT: I saw your webpage, and it seems to work fine! Have you fixed your issue or are you still struggling?

Comment: I forgot to thank you sir. I solved it by creating an if statement for the `for jtag in json_tags` and some others lines.

Here are the new link since the old link only shows products from Shopee.

https://hidden-temple-70386.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Data isn't being created. Probably because `json_tags` is empty. Log the results of `page_response.text` and check that it looks like it should.

```
page_link = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q='+keyword+'&sort=priceasc'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = soup(page_response.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I did put print(json_tags) to test the log, it gives me exactly the one that will be used in the for loop to including the creation of data['itemListElement']

Comment: Did you run `print(json_tags)` on heroku?

Comment: I have logged the results of `page_content` on heroku, it did not give me the same soup (html tags) as the one that I get when run on localhost. How is that possible?

Comment: I found out that my code (lazada part) is only working on localhost, but not working when I'm using the one in Heroku and any other online python editor

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem by just putting those 3 parts in an if else condition.

So below is the new full code for my system.

But there is a problem where lazada blocked the ip from heroku, so the system only shows result from shopee & lelong.

Here are the new link : https://unifit-apps.herokuapp.com/

Thats it for now. Thank you!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from functools import wraps
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

app = Flask(__name__)

# Results
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    query = request.form['keyword']
    results = extract(query)
    return jsonify(results)

class Products(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, price=None, image=None, url=None, origin=None):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.image = image
        self.url = url
        self.origin = origin

# Extract
@app.route('/extract', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def extract(keyword):
    if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'GET':
        x = {}
        x['items'] = []

        # Shopee Starts Here
        l1 = []

        url = "https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/"

        querystring = {"by":"relevancy","keyword":keyword,"limit":"20","locations":"-1","match_id":"174","newest":"0","order":"desc","page_type":"search","rating_filter":"4"}


        payload = ""
        headers = {
        'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
        'accept': "*/*",
        'x-api-source': "pc",
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        'if-none-match-': "55b03-e2b4b3f247507f7c1a18fda4a09f1340",
        'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
        'connection': "keep-alive",
        'host': "shopee.com.my"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        results = json_data["items"]

        if results:

            for item in results:
                name = item["name"]
                price = float(item["price"])/100000
                imagex = item["image"]
                image = "https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/" + imagex
                shopid = item["shopid"]
                itemid = item["itemid"]
                url = "https://shopee.com.my/"+name+"-i."+str(shopid)+"."+str(itemid)
                origin = "Shopee"

                l1.append(Products(name, float(price), image, url, origin))

        # Shopee Ends Here

        # Lazada Starts Here
        l2 = []

        page_link = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page=1&q='+keyword+'&sort=priceasc'
        # https://www.lazada.com.my/shop-computers-laptops/?q=arctis&from=input
        page_response = requests.get(page_link)
        page_content = soup(page_response.text, "html.parser")

        json_tags = page_content.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})
        if json_tags:
            for jtag in json_tags:
                json_text = jtag.get_text()
                data = json.loads(json_text)

            lazada = data['itemListElement']

            for item in lazada:
                name = item["name"]
                image = item["image"]
                price = item["offers"]["price"]
                url = item["url"]
                origin = "Lazada"

                l2.append(Products(name, float(price), image, url, origin))



        # Lazada Stops Here

        # Lelong Starts Here
        l3 = []

        url = "https://www.lelong.com.my/catalog/all/list?TheKeyword="+keyword+"&CategoryID=51"

        payload = ""
        headers = {
            'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
            'accept': "*/*",
            'x-api-source': "pc",
            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
            'if-none-match-': "55b03-e2b4b3f247507f7c1a18fda4a0f91340",
            'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
            'connection': "keep-alive",
            }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)        
        page_content = soup(response.text, "html.parser")

        json_tags = page_content.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})

        if json_tags:
            for jtag in json_tags:
                json_text = jtag.get_text()
                json_dict = json.loads(json_text)

            lelong = json_dict['itemListElement']

            for item in lelong:
                name = item["name"]
                image = item["image"]
                price = item["offers"]["price"].replace(',', '')
                url = item["url"]
                origin = "Lelong"

                l3.append(Products(name, float(price), image, url, origin))

        # Lelong Stops Here

        # Combine result
        mergelist = l1+l2+l3
        import operator
        mergelist.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('price'))

        # Tukar dari list ke json
        for elem in mergelist:
            x['items'].append({  
                'name': elem.name,
                'price': float(elem.price),
                'image': elem.image,
                'url': elem.url,
                'origin': elem.origin
            })

        #print(json.dumps(x, indent=2))
        mergelist = json.dumps(x, indent=2)

    return mergelist

# Main
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')

# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```